# Command line script for Offline Files in Windows XP Professional

Tags: windows-xp, sync, home-networking

I want to write a bat script to have the same functionality as mentioned in this [article][1]

[1]: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/mobility/learnmore/offlinefiles.mspx .

What would be the steps/commands used for fast syncs ?

Comment: Will this work on a XP Home edition machine?

Comment: Good question!  So that I understand the question - you're looking for a script that adjusts some specified folders desktop.ini so that it will get synchronised for offline use?

Comment: Do you want your solution to be free?  What are you willing to pay for a 'windows native' solution?

Comment: I want similar functionality because I have trouble when explorer crashes

Answer (score 1):

Doing that in a batch script would be fairly challenging to say the least.

Why not use rsync -avz? It's free at least, and rsync is quite fast, as it performs differential backups.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in a .bat file would indeed be challenging.  But, why not create a batch file to run the .vbs?  Would that suit your purpose?  If so, create a blank .bat file and put the following inside:

cscript NameOfVBSFile.vbs /

Where NameOfVBSFile.vbs is the... name of the VBS file you want to run and
where  are the switches you need for the VBS to do its job.

As for the .vbs, try one of these:

Sync entire cache:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2007/04/26/cscsyncall-vbs-sync-the-entire-offline-files-cache.aspx

Sync specific UNC path:
replace last part of URL with cscsync-vbs-sync-a-particular-unc-path.aspx
(new user, so superuser.com says I can only post one URL as some sort of anti-spam control)

Best of luck,
Chris

Comment: The vbs script in the link applies to vista/windows 7, not for xp.

Answer (score 0):

'csccmd /fill' can be used to sync offline marked shares.

More info on csccmd is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884739